# Homework help. From spivak calculus book

Tags: calculus

Show that $f$ is convex on an interval if and only if for all $x$ and $y$ in the interval we have  $$f(tx+(1-t)y)<tf(x)+(1-t)f(y),  0<t<1$$

The only thing I know is that we have to approach it by using the definition of convexity

The definition in the textbook is

> A  function  $f$ is said to be convex on an interval if for $a,x,b$ in the interval
>   with $a<x<b$ we have $$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} < \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

Comment: What definition is Spivak using for convexity here?

Comment: @SimonS I've updated the question with spivak's definition

Comment: What is your try?

Comment: @Paul I tried to show that points in $(x,y)$ are precisely those of the form $tx+(1-t)y$ and I failed to obtain it. Not even sure if its correct

Comment: FYI, that is a definition of *strict* convexity... Strictly speaking ;-) Relax the inequalities to $\le$ to get standard convexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to substitute $b=y$, $a=x$, and $x=ta+(1-t)b$ in the definition. Do the $x=ta+(1-t)b$ substitution, notice you can cancel a factor $(a-b)$ from both sides, and then rearrange to get a formula in terms of $a$ and $b$, then substitute $a\rightarrow x$ and $b\rightarrow y$ in that.

Comment: do i need to prove first that for any set $(x,y)$, $tx+(1-t)y \in (x,y)$ if $0<t<1$?

Comment: @Hobbit6094 Yes you would need that result, but I think that is assumed at this point, so you wouldn't usually specifically need to prove it in your answer to this question.

Comment: Could you check if this proof is OK?, for any any set $(x,y)$, $x<y$,  then since $t<1$, then $(1-t)x<(1-t)y$, then $0<(1-t)y - (1-t)x $, so $0<(1-t)y-x+tx$, then $x<(1-t)y+tx$. Another side  $x<y$, then $tx<ty$, and $tx-ty<0$, then $tx-ty+y<y$, so $tx+(1-t)y<y$

Comment: @Hobbit6094 That looks ok, except it would be better to use "so" rather than "then" when one conclusion depends on another one.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $x<y$. Notice that (by the defintion)

$$ \frac{f(tx+(1-t)y)-f(x)}{tx+(1-t)y-x}<\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$$

i.e.,

$$\frac{f(tx+(1-t)y)-f(x)}{(1-t)(y-x)}< \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$$

And hence

$$f(tx+(1-t)y)-f(x) < (1-t)(f(y)-f(x))$$

which implies that $$f(tx+(1-t)y) < tf(x) + (1-t)f(y)$$

Comment: @SuzuHirose Thanks!

Comment: O, ya! I should beat my haed on the desk!